# How can I call a angular JavaScript function inside a cordova function

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova

I am trying to either get a function to return true or false or see if I can call another function inside of this one.

```js
checkLocationIsOn() {
  cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
    console.log('GPS location is ' + (enabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'));
}, function(error) {
    console.error('The following error occurred: ' + error);
}
);
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(this.onRequestSuccess, this.onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

This function checks to see if the users GPS is enabled on there phone what I need is for it to return true or false or call a javascript function. I have already tried to call another function using this.testfunction(); but when I run it on my device it gives me an arror saying function this.testfunction() undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you have lost context, there's two way:

1. using fat arrow function
2. using `bind(this)`

example of both approach:

```
cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(data => this.onRequestSuccess(data), this.onRequestFailure.bind(this), cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Comment: No no both of those functions work fine its if I try call a function within those functions then it tells me the function I am trying to call isan't defined